# Why is my dictionary printed in the wrong order as the input it's iterating over?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

My example input is as follows:

```
example_input = "John is connected to Bryant, Debra, Walter.\
John likes to play The Movie: The Game, The Legend of Corgi, Dinosaur Diner.\
Bryant is connected to Olive, Ollie, Freda, Mercedes.\
Bryant likes to play City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma, Super Mushroom Man.\
Mercedes is connected to Walter, Robin, Bryant.\
Mercedes likes to play The Legend of Corgi, Pirates in Java Island, Seahorse Adventures.\
Olive is connected to John, Ollie.\
Olive likes to play The Legend of Corgi, Starfleet Commander.\
Debra is connected to Walter, Levi, Jennie, Robin.\
Debra likes to play Seven Schemers, Pirates in Java Island, Dwarves and Swords.\
Walter is connected to John, Levi, Bryant.\
Walter likes to play Seahorse Adventures, Ninja Hamsters, Super Mushroom Man.\
Levi is connected to Ollie, John, Walter.\
Levi likes to play The Legend of Corgi, Seven Schemers, City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma.\
Ollie is connected to Mercedes, Freda, Bryant.\
Ollie likes to play Call of Arms, Dwarves and Swords, The Movie: The Game.\
Jennie is connected to Levi, John, Freda, Robin.\
Jennie likes to play Super Mushroom Man, Dinosaur Diner, Call of Arms.\
Robin is connected to Ollie.\
Robin likes to play Call of Arms, Dwarves and Swords.\
Freda is connected to Olive, John, Debra.\
Freda likes to play Starfleet Commander, Ninja Hamsters, Seahorse Adventures."
```

I am trying to input this information into a dictionary in the following format, e.g: `{'John':{'connected':[],'likes':[]}}` and have managed to get the dictionary of names with their connected dictionary. However, I am unable to fill out the `connected` and `likes` lists as when I iterate through my `get_name` function, the order is returned messed up and makes it difficult for me to add the correct information into the dictionary.

Here's my code:

```
def get_name(string_input):
    l = [line.split('is connected to') for i, line in enumerate(string_input.split('.')) if i % 2 == 0]
    name = {}
    names = {name[0]:{'connected':[],'likes':[]} for name in l} 
    return names

print get_name(example_input)
```

Comment: Dictionary is un ordered type by default. consider using ordered dictionary if it matters to you.

Comment: Use an ordered dictionary.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects

Answer (score 2):

Dict is not an ordered type.

If you need it ordered use `OrderedDict()` from the `collections` library.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer for this question